# Adding data to a list on another page Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of event name in a stateful widget like this

```
main.dart

class Fav extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FavState createState() => _FavState();
}

class _FavState extends State<Fav> {
  final PageController ctrl = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8);

  final Firestore db = Firestore.instance;
  Stream slides;

  var fav = ['3-Tech Event']; 
. 
.
.
```

And on another page, I want to add a string, let's say,

`'5-Art Exhibit'`

into the

`var fav = ['3-Tech Event'];`

to get the final result

`fav = ['3-Tech Event', '5-Art Exhibit'];`

on the page above. How do I do that? Here's my code for the button

```
Event.dart

class Star extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _StarState createState() => _StarState();
    }

    class _StarState extends State<Star> {
      Color _iconColor = Colors.grey;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(55.0),
              child: Transform.scale(
                scale: 2.0,
                  child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.star,
                        color: _iconColor,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _iconColor = (_iconColor == Colors.yellow) ?  Colors.grey : Colors.yellow;

                        });
                      })
              ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**

I followed @Viren V Varasadiya advice and updated my code to this

```dart
main.dart

class Fav extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _FavState createState() => _FavState();
}

class _FavState extends State<Fav> {

  var fav = ['3-Tech Event'];
  updatedata(String item) {
    setState(() {
      fav.add(item);
    });
  }
```

And on the other file, I removed Star class (because it's intended to be used in another class anyway) and it looked like this

```dart
class Event extends StatefulWidget {
  final eventInfo;
  Event({Key key, List eventInfo})    //I have to pass a list of data to this 
      : this.eventInfo = eventInfo,   //page from another class
        super(key: key);

  final Function updatedata;
  Event.addToFavWith({this.updatedata});

  @override
  _EventState createState() => _EventState();
}

class _EventState extends State<Event> {
  Color _iconColor = Colors.grey;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
.
.
.
Container(                          //This used to be Container(child:Star())
          child: InkWell(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(55.0),
          child: Transform.scale(
              scale: 2.0,
              child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.star,
                    color: _iconColor,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _iconColor = (_iconColor == Colors.yellow)
                          ? Colors.grey
                          : Colors.yellow;
                      widget.updatedata(name);
                    });
                  })),
        ),
      )),
```

And now I get a couple of errors.

> All final variables must be initialized, but 'eventInfo' is not. Try
>   adding an initializer for the field.
>
> All final variables must be initialized, but 'updatedata' is not. Try
>   adding an initializer for the field.

Comment: let me clear more. you want to update fav from Star? are you using star widget in that class(fav)? if yes then also add that part of code.

Comment: When you navigate to a new function, you can pass a function that takes in an argument of event name and adds it to the list. On the second page you can call this function reference

Comment: Yes, I want to update fav by pressing on a star icon. The widget `Star` is not in the `Fav` but it's in a separate dart file. @VirenVVarasadiya
How do I call a function from a different dart file? @Abbas

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a function in parent widget and pass it to child widget and call it in child widget, we work for you.

Following minimal code help you more.

```
class DeleteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DeleteWidgetState createState() => _DeleteWidgetState();
}

class _DeleteWidgetState extends State<DeleteWidget> {
  var fav = ['3-Tech Event'];

  updatedata(String item) {
    setState(() {
      fav.add(item);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(fav.toString()),
        Star(
          updatedata: updatedata,
        ),
      ],
    )));
  }
}

class Star extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function updatedata;
  Star({this.updatedata});
  @override
  _StarState createState() => _StarState();
}

class _StarState extends State<Star> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("add item"),
          onPressed: () {
            widget.updatedata('5-Art Exhibit');
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Update:

There is no need to create named constructor.

```
class Event extends StatefulWidget {
  final eventInfo;
  Event({Key key, List eventInfo, this.updatedata})    //I have to pass a list of data to this 
      : this.eventInfo = eventInfo,   //page from another class
        super(key: key);

  final Function updatedata;

  @override
  _EventState createState() => _EventState();
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. I get this in the debug console

`type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Function'`

I don't get it. Didn't we just try to pass the String into the function?

Comment: are you talking about my demo ? because my demo is working completely fine.

Comment: No, I add the `updatedata ` and `final Function updatedata;

  Star({this.updatedata});` 

like your example into my code. Is it because my Star class and Fav class are in differents files?? I don't get how the function works. I'm sorry I just started learning flutter.

Comment: code in different file doesn’t matter. can you update you question with current situation ? so i become easy for me to understand and also add some more details what exactly you want and how in your update. @BookTeeranai

Comment: you have to pass updatedata function where you are calling that widget. @BookTeeranai

Comment: Got this ```The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: [](6)``` in the debug console. Does having the list empty (fav = []) cause the problem?

Comment: you have to initialise at list like var a = [];

Comment: Even when I put something in the list it still throws ```The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: [](6)``` at me on Fav widget. And when I tap the star button in Event widget I got this ```The method 'call' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: call("5-Art exhibit")```
I'm sorry this takes a lot of your effort but I'm trying my best

Comment: add where you are calling Event.

Comment: What do you mean by that? The ```The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: [](6)``` only show up when I put ```Event(updatedata: updatedata)``` in the Fav widget. Do I need that to make it works? Because all I need is just to add the data to the list.

Comment: it should work fine. if you pass function to event class and initialise list as i mention. add full code otherwise i can't help anymore.